# My Javascript CountdownTimer wont show up?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Hi I am trying to build a basic countdown timer but somehow the html countdown timer I coded wont show up. Could anybody give any suggestions or example code on what I should code I already cleaned up the code a-lot.

```js
const days = document.getElementById('days')
const hours = document.getElementById('hours')
const minutes = document.getElementById('minutes')
const seconds = document.getElementById('seconds')

const newYears = '1 Jan 2021';

function countdown () {
  const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
  const currentDate = new Date ();
  
  const totalSeconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;
  const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24);
  const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  const minutes= Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
  const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;
  console.log(newYearsDate - currentDate)
  
  days.innerHTML = days;
  hours.innerHTML = hours;
  minutes.innerHTML = minutes;
  seconds.innerHTML = seconds;
}
countdown()

setInterval(countdown, 1000)
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="color:white">
    <a href="https://postimg.cc/HcqsMVZP" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HcqsMVZP/NY-K13-large-small.jpg" border="0" alt="NY-K13-large-small" width="300" height="500"></a>
    <h1>Countdown-Timer</h1>
    <div class="Countdown-Timer">
        <div class="days">
            <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
            <span>days</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hours">
            <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
            <span>hours</span>
        </div>
        <div class="minutes">
            <p class="big-text" id="minutes">0</p>
            <span>minutes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="seconds">
            <p class="big-text" id="days">0</p>
            <span>seconds</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're overwriting your `days`, etc. variables. Call them something different.

Comment: Also, you have 2 elements with `id="hours"`. ID's should be unique!

Answer (score 0):

Change your body text color to black otherwise you wont see your numbers, change the name of your variables so that they refer to correct ones when consumed (separate variables for DOM objects, separate ones for calculation).

Your id's need to be unique: days, hours, minutes, seconds.

Would be nice to move your **span** before the **p** so that the UI is more meaningful.

```js
const days = document.getElementById('days')
const hours = document.getElementById('hours')
const minutes = document.getElementById('minutes')
const seconds = document.getElementById('seconds')

const newYears = '1 Jan 2021';

function countdown() {
  const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
  const currentDate = new Date();

  const totalSeconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;
  const days1 = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24);
  const hours1 = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  const minutes1 = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
  const seconds1 = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60;
  // console.log(newYearsDate - currentDate)

  days.innerHTML = days1;
  hours.innerHTML = hours1;
  minutes.innerHTML = minutes1;
  seconds.innerHTML = seconds1;
}
countdown()

setInterval(countdown, 1000)
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body style="color:black">
    <a href="https://postimg.cc/HcqsMVZP" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/HcqsMVZP/NY-K13-large-small.jpg" border="0" alt="NY-K13-large-small" width="300" height="500"></a>
    <h1>Countdown-Timer</h1>
    <div class="Countdown-Timer">
      <div class="days">
        <p class="big-text" id="days">0</p>
        <span>days</span>
      </div>
      <div class="hours">
        <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
        <span>hours</span>
      </div>
      <div clas="minutes">
        <p class="big-text" id="minutes">0</p>
        <span>minutes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="seconds">
        <p class="big-text" id="seconds">0</p>
        <span>seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```